# JBoss 7 ServiceLoader

Tags: jboss7.x, serviceloader

There is an intefrace **MyIntefrace**.

System has several EARs, each with own implementations of that intefrace. I need to find all implementations without their names (**? extends MyInterface**).

I decided to use **java.util.ServiceLoader** and created a jar with META-INF/services/com.example.MyInterface inside it, ant this jar can be deployed in any of EARs.

The jar has a servlet and following code inside int's init method:

```
ServiceLoader<MyInterface > loader = ServiceLoader.load(MyInterface .class);
Iterator<MyInterface > it = loader.iterator();
```

But iterator still empty..

I tryed to add services/com.example.MyInterface in EARs META-INF, but result is the same.

That approach works fine in jboss 6 and tomcat.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: each EAR must has META-INF/services/com.example.MyInterface text file with enumeration of the all implementations inside that EAR

Comment: Are you saying that using the ServiceLoader architecture you were able to discover services between separate EAR deployments? i.e. EAR1 can find services in EAR2, without declaring a direct dependency on each other? (through manifest or jboss-deployment-structure.xml)

Comment: no, each EAR has own classloader and ServiceLoader will load only those who in parent EAR

Answer (score 3):

When i had the same problem, it was solved by trying lazyloading

```
private static class LoaderHolder {
   ServiceLoader<MyInterface > loader = ServiceLoader.load(MyInterface .class);
  }

Iterator<MyInterface > it = LoaderHolder .loader.iterator();
```